# SQL Server Buffer cache content

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm having an issue on my instance page life expectancy would drop to a few seconds.
I know this is due bad code, and I'm trying to find out which object pages are in the buffer cache. That would lead me to what causes the problem. Kind of v$bh equivalent in Oracle.

**Edit**

I came across [this great article](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Performance-issues-from-wasted-buffer-pool-memory.aspx) which talk about the issue I got with pagelife expectancy. And how to find the buffer content.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link should provide you with the queries to use for this: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2393/determine-sql-server-memory-use-by-database-and-object/

Note: You didnt' say which version of SQL Server you are using, but this will only work on 2005 and up boxes

Comment: Thanks a lot! works like a charm. I've added an sp_foreachdb, and got all of what I needed. Oh, and by the way, 2008r2 is my version.

Answer (score 0):

[`sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173442%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) has the data about buffer pool content. You will also be interested in [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [`sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Between these you will be able to identify hot objects. [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) will show you queries that are touching a lot of pages (high logical_reads).

Comment: Thanks, sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors is what I was after. I guess my next step is to find how I can me an object not to pin in the buffer pool. I have 64GB of RAM, and most of it's content doesn't need to be.

Comment: IS the 64GB available to SQL? What does [`DBCC MEMORYSTATUS`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271624) return?

Comment: Yes it is. Server has 96G total, and 64G allocated to MSSQL (Only cause the 64G limit in standard). I just have objects in cache that don't need to be, along with badly coded app.